# Alice Bundle : dynamic entity loop parameter

Tags: php, symfony, faker, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I use [Hautelook AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) which use [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to generate fixtures with real world data.

In Alice, we can use parameters in our YAML file like below:

```
parameters:
  pwd_parameter:   anything

My\UserEntity:
  #generate 10 users with password equals to my parameter
  user_{1..10}:
    password:      '<{pwd_parameter}>'
```

Is it possible to use parameters to generate dynamic numbers of fixtures?

The solution I am looking for is to do this:

```
parameters:
  pwd_parameter:   anything
  nb_users:        10

My\UserEntity:
  #generate nb_users users with password equals to my parameter
  user_{1..nb_users}:   #<---THIS IS THE PROBLEM
      password:    '<{pwd_parameter}>
```

I tried:

```
user_{1..  nb_users   }
user_{1.. <nb_users>  }
user_{1..<{nb_users}> }
user_{1..<{nb_users}> }
```

which throws:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

How can I generate my number of entities dynamically?

Comment: It's configuration, you can't do that. Unless, you create bundle extension to read dynamic bundle parse by your code and put to paramaters

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do something like that since fixtures yaml configuration files do not get merged with symfony parameters.

`Nelmio\Alice\Fixtures\Fixture\RangeName` is the class used to validate and parse configuration from your example.
Take a look at `RangeName::canBuild()` and you'll see regular expression that validates yaml key.

You could create your own Builder Method that would randomize number of fixture rows inserted.

Comment: Thanks, it put me toward the right direction. Do you know how can I add my custom builder to the existing one? I've seen the `Fixtures\Loader` class but i can't find how to add mine without writing in my vendor class

Comment: The parameters are not symfony one, it is used by alice as you can see in `password:      '<{pwd_parameter}>' `

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/nelmio/alice/pull/136/commits someone already created a pull request for it. It's for 1.x but might help you.